# PHP 7.4 Extensions Such as SQLite3 Not Built by Default

Tags: php, macos, homebrew

I've installed PHP 7.4.11 on macOS using Homebrew.

When I tried to enable extensions which are built with PHP, such as **sqlite3** and **pdo_sqlite**, the extensions couldn't be found, as implied from the following warnings:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlite' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/pdo_sqlite (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/pdo_sqlite, 9): image not found), /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/pdo_sqlite.so (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/pdo_sqlite.so, 9): image not found)) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlite' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/pdo_sqlite (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/pdo_sqlite, 9): image not found), /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/pdo_sqlite.so (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/pdo_sqlite.so, 9): image not found)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sqlite3' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/sqlite3 (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/sqlite3, 9): image not found), /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/sqlite3.so (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/sqlite3.so, 9): image not found)) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sqlite3' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/sqlite3 (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/sqlite3, 9): image not found), /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/sqlite3.so (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/sqlite3.so, 9): image not found)) in Unknown on line 0
```

In my extension's directory, `/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/`, there is not a single file. I expected shared object (.so) files for all the extensions built with PHP.

I also tried installing PHP 8.0 using the command `brew install php --HEAD`, but the problem persists. According to the Homebrew formula for PHP, all these extensions such as sqlite3, pdo_sqlite, etc should be built with PHP.

Can anyone tell me how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: You could use laradock (www.laradock.io) and run everything via docker, not having to pollute your host OS. You can also compile the extension yourself (google for phpize).

Comment: Good idea. However, I did I build PHP from source using `brew install php --HEAD`. It compiled everything on my system and I analyzed the commands involved in the build process. It configured PHP to include sqlite and other extensions - you can check the Homebrew formula yourself. I think this problem is easy to reproduce. Wish someone could identify what is going on.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had to manually fix the problem by compiling the extensions with phpize. However, I want to understand why the extensions weren't built in the first place. This is why I'm keeping the question open.